Why are the initial conditions insufficient to determine final pressure and temperature?
Suppose two adiabatic tanks of volume $V_1,V_2$, connected using a valve, contain helium gas at $P_1,T_1$ and $P_2,T_2$ respectively. The valve is opened and the tanks come to a uniform state. Determine the final pressure and temperature of the gas.
If they depend on each other and cannot be determined using the initial parameters, explain why.

My attempt: Let $x$ be the final number of moles in tank $B$. Then the final number of moles in tank $A$ are $(n_1+n_2-x)$ where $n_1,n_2$ are given by:
$n_1=\dfrac{P_1V_1}{RT_1},n_2=\dfrac{P_2V_2}{RT_2}$
Thus, $P_fV_1=(n_1+n_2-x)RT_f$ and $P_fV_2=xRT_f$. Substituting from above, and adding the two equations, we obtain:
$$P_f = \left(\frac{P_1V_1T_2+P_2V_2T_1}{T_1T_2(V_1+V_2)} \right) T_f$$
i.e. the final pressure depends on the final temperature linearly, so although the initial state of the system is perfectly known, there are infinitely many possible final states of the system!
I think the reason is that we do not know the precise mechanism of the valve and the work done in opening the valve; we know that there is no heat transfer with the surrounding, so $\Delta Q=0 \implies \Delta U_1 + \Delta U_2 + W = 0$. If the work done in opening the valve was $0$, then the final temperature would be the mean of the initial temperatures weighted by the number of moles; $T_f=\dfrac{n_1T_1+n_2T_2}{n_1+n_2}$, which intuitively makes sense, especially in the case where the number of moles in both tanks is equal. This would make the pressure the mean of the initial pressures weighted by volume; $P_f=\dfrac{P_1V_1+P_2V_2}{V_1+V_2}$. Also, the number of moles transferred from $A$ to $B$ in this case will be $$\Delta n =\frac{1}{R}\frac{V_1V_2}{V_1+V_2}\left(\frac{P_1}{T_1}-\frac{P_2}{T_2} \right)$$
Is there any other subtler reason I am missing?

You seem to be overcomplicating this.  You only need to consider the initial and final equilibrium states for an ideal gas and the fact that the two tank system is an isolated system ($\Delta U_{total}=0$).

Why do you think that, given the initial conditions, the final conditions can not be determined?

Because, I have 3 equations (ideal gas eqn for both tanks and FLOT) and 4 variables ($P_f,T_f,x,W$).

Also, I don't think the two-tank system is isolated because there is energy input in the form of shaft work involved in turning the valve.

@Cognoscenti the "valve" can be theoretically electrically opened by an internal (e.g. battery) source.  I really think you can forget about the valve.

There is Negligible shaft work done by turning the valves. So what’s the problem then?

Suppose the two tanks were insulated and the pipe joining them was also insulated so that you couldn’t conduct heat from one tank to the other. Would that change your conclusion that the final temperature is uniform in both tanks? How would you handle this case?
